# Internal Server Error while create a customer via API magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Аfter research I found error line. Its module \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement, funciton createAccountWithPasswordHash(), line 883: $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(); In this place I get 500 Internal Server Error. What's wrong? We have multistore and they works perfect but maybe I have to set some extra/hidden setting?

Comment: What's your api call and payload? Also, what exactly does the error say?

Comment: Payload and req looks like here https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/create-customer-magento-2.html Error says "nothing" - code working up to and including the password checking and on line $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId() code die without error and messages.